# How to convert set of string from map values of string using stream API in java

Tags: java, java-stream

I'd like to make Set from the values in Map<String, String>.

The following code doesn't work.
How to fix it?

```
Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
testMap.put("test", "1234");
Map<String, String> testMap2 = new HashMap<>();
testMap.put("test", "12345");
List<Map<String, String>> testList = new ArrayList<>();
testList.add(testMap);
testList.add(testMap2);
Set<String> testSet = testList.stream().map(item -> item.get("test")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

+++
This code below is wokring, but I'd like to use stream API

```
Set<String> set= new HashSet<>(); 
for (HashMap testMap : testMapList) 
      set.add(testMap.get("test"));
```

Comment: ```testMap.put("test", "12345");``` -> ```testMap2.put("test", "12345");```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check which map you are using to put the values
you used the same testMap instead of testMap2 to put the values.

Additionally, I filter for nonNull values.

```
 Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
        testMap.put("test", "1234");
        Map<String, String> testMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        testMap2.put("test", "12345");
        List<Map<String, String>> testList = new ArrayList<>();
        testList.add(testMap);
        testList.add(testMap2);
        Set<String> testSet = testList.stream().map(item -> item.get("test")).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toSet()); // [1234, 12345]
```

[image]

Comment: I need to use list of maps..so I wanna select values of each of maps and make them set.

Comment: check my answer it should work. you have some typo in your code

Comment: your code isn't working.. with no type

Comment: Set<String> set= new HashSet<>();
     for (HashMap testMap : testMapList) {
      set.add(testMap .get("test"));
         }
This is working, but I'd like to use stream API

Comment: what is the output you are looking

Comment: Let me check again..something must've been wrong with my code. Thank you!

Comment: check the 11th line